# I have to re-pair my bluetooth earphones everytime otherwise they do not output sound

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire

I have a pair of samsung galaxy buds+ earphones and have been using them on my ubuntu desktop. The problem is that everytime I disconnect them, the time I take them out of the case again, they get connected with the PC but don't output any sound. No sound profile appears associated with them and the sound output comes through the other speakers. If I remove the device and pair again, it works until the next time I keep the buds.

I am currently using PulseAudio. Tried switching to pipewire but then the A2DP profile did not work at all, so I switched back to PulseAudio.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

My log files have many instances, I believe regarding this issue:

```
src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX: Device or resource busy

src/service.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername"Transport enfpoint is not connected (107)

src/profile.x:ext_start_servers() RFCOMM server failed for Headser unit: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title and the answer inside the question. Press the **Answer Your Own Question** to answer your question. Then accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅.

Comment: @user68186 thank you for guiding me here! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply uninstalling and purging PulseAudio and rebooting the PC. Now PipeWire is on and fully functional. I have to manually switch to HSP profile when I have to use the microphone, but at least now I can go back to A2DP whenever I want to. Leaving it here in case someone has the same problem in the future.